# What does 'spook credentials' mean?

Tags: phrases, noun-phrases

I've encountered this expression on the book "UNIX: A History and a Memoir".

> One day I was scheduled to do a demo for William Colby, who at the time was the director of the Central Intelligence Agency (CIA), and thus clearly an important person. He too would be accompanied by Bill Baker, who as head of the President’s Foreign Intelligence Advisory Board had serious **spook credentials** of his own.

I searched it on the web and got some results from English websites, but no proper explanation anywhere. There wasn't any usage on my local language web sites.

Could someone explain the meaning and general usage of the expression?

Comment: He too was a high-ranking member of the intelligence fraternity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Spook' (an informal word for a ghost or spirit) is also a mainly US English slang word for a spy, secret agent, etc. To have credentials in something means to have qualifications, experience or knowledge in that field. Both named men were members of the US government intelligence community.

> spook noun [C] (PERSON)   slang
>
> spy

[Spook (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spook)

> credentials
>
> noun [ plural ]   abilities and experience that make someone suitable
>   for a particular job or activity:
>
> business/educational/professional credentials
>
> He is keen for people to know his business credentials.

[Credentials (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/credentials)